# How to change a forgotten password while I am logged in already

Tags: windows, windows-10

I have forgotten the local password to my windows 10 laptop.   This is no big deal, because I just logged in using the fingerprint scanner.

However I would like to change the password in case the fingerprint scanner stops working.

When I try to, windows asks me for the old password which I do not know.

How do I change the password?

Comment: Are you an administrator?

Comment: Did you link your account to a Microsoft Account?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Change user password in Windows 10, via NET USER command, without knowing the current password](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/149427):

```
C:\Windows\system32> net user WindowsAccountName *
Type a password for the user:
Retype the password to confirm:
The passwords do not match.

Type a password for the user:
Retype the password to confirm:
The command completed successfully.
```

[Works in Windows 10 as well](http://www.softwareok.com/?seite=faq-Windows-10&faq=56) from command prompt (`cmd.exe`) started in administrative mode e.g. via <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> -> *Command Prompt (Admin)*.

Otherwise you get (all examples from Windows 8):

```
==> net user WindowsAccountName *
Type a password for the user:
Retype the password to confirm:
System error 5 has occurred.

Access is denied.
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't mention which version of Windows 10 you're running, but if you are on the Pro version, you can do this from the Local Users and Groups node of the Computer Management console.

Right-click on your Start button and hit Computer Management.  Then expand the Local Users and Groups node, and click on users.  Then right-click your user account and hit "Set Password...".  Your old password will not be required.

NOTE that this only works if you are running the Pro or Enterprise versions of Windows 10, and won't work if you're using a Microsoft account to sign in.